# 422 Tika server response? Tika-Python

Tags: python, pdf, apache-tika, http-status-code-422, tika-server

I have been trying to get Apache-Tika to work with this python package: https://github.com/chrismattmann/tika-python

I have the following code in my python program:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import tika
tika.initVM()
from tika import parser
parsed = parser.from_file('pdf/myPdf.pdf')
```

But I get a 422 response every time:

```
[MainThread  ] [WARNI]  Failed to see startup log message; retrying...
[MainThread  ] [WARNI]  Tika server returned status: 422
```

Apache Tika does work when I use the following command:

```
java -jar tika-app-1.18.jar -t pdf/alnaggar2016lattice.pdf
```

I really would like to fix this error with the Tika-Python package because it would be a lot easier for the rest of the project if this would work.

Comment: The Tika Python library is a wrapper around the Tika Server jar, rather than the CLI Tika App jar. Does the Tika Server jar start properly for you?

Comment: I have tried the command above with the tika jar file and it didn't give me any errors when I ran it. @Gagravarr

Comment: Tika App != Tika Server - what happens if you try to start the *Tika Server* standalone?

Comment: When I run the server jar file with this command: `java -jar tika-server-1.18.jar -h 0.0.0.0` It doesn't give me any errors and starts up fine. @Gagravarr

Comment: Best ask on the Tika Users list, the main maintainer of the Tika Python integration tends not to be on StackOverflow much, but is on the Tika mailing lists!

Comment: Http: 422 code is interesting and I get it. a lot when putting files through Tika that just contain images - So a PDF with an image, Tika knows the file type, but cannot process the file, as it's an image.

What I have done to circumvent this is to use headers:

            headers = {'X-Tika-PDFextractInlineImages': 'true',}  

            data = parser.from_file(pathtofile, serverEndpoint=self.TIKA_SERVER, headers=headers)

Comment: So the issue was the PDF was corrupted

Comment: tika is one of the worst projects I have ever seen, lacking or incorrect documentation, constant errors at runtime, very slow. Unnecessarily verbose and incomprehensible source code. Think about it 10 times before using it. I strongly advise against.