# How to handle Tika Server Warning 422 when the problem is not related to the pdf?

Tags: python, apache-tika

My problem is very similar to this person's problem:

[422 Tika server response? Tika-Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52196544/422-tika-server-response-tika-python)

But not exactly. His problem seems to be with reading certain documents but Tika is working fine, whereas for me the docs are fine, but Tika is failing. I have used the following python code in the past as recent as 4 weeks ago with no problems:

```
from tika import unpack
result = unpack.from_file(file)
```

[Note: I was not able to indent the above code.  It would just skip down to the next section]

What happens when I use this code is that it simply outputs an empty dictionary.  And I receive the warning:

> Tika server returned status:422

But no error message. This happens with all of my PDF docs so the problem is not the PDF doc. Further, I have used this exact same code regularly in the past with no problems.  I have absolutely no experience with Tika and only use this small line of code because when I use Python's pdfviewer it does not work.  So this is the only package that I have found which can read the PDF's I'm interested in. I tried redownloading Tika with `pip install Tika` but the requirements are already satisfied. I also tried this command line:

```
java -jar tika-app.jar -s file.pdf
```

But I received the error message:

> Error: Unable to access jarfile tika-app.jar

I did some research on how to handle that error so input into command line:

```
java -jar tika-server-1.18.jar -h 0.0.0.0
```

But that returned the message:

> Error: Unable to access jarfile tika-server-1.18.jar

Usually what happens when I used Tika is that it does take a while to get the app running whereas this is not happening this time around.  Maybe the problem is just that I cannot get the app running.  The online Tika documentation assumes that the reader already has quite a lot of experience with front end programming whereas all of my experience is with backend programming, so I cannot make heads or tails of the Tika documentation whatsoever.

Comment: If you can't find your Tika jar, why not just download it from [the Apache Tika website](https://tika.apache.org/download.html) to test with standalone?

Comment: Thanks for helping me out but I have all of the Tika software I need.  As I said in my OP: "I have used the following python code in the past as recent as 4 weeks ago with no problems".  I also said: "I tried redownloading Tika with pip install Tika but the requirements are already satisfied. I also tried this command line".  In any case, recall that I also said: "all of my experience is with backend programming, so I cannot make heads or tails of the Tika documentation whatsoever," so when you say 'standalone' I really don't know what you mean.

Comment: Most Tika users are backend users! Just download the Tika App jar (standalone, single jar), run your problem file through that, and look at the error given, then let us know what it says. The python wrapper is lovely when it works, but it hides some stuff you need when things go wrong...

Comment: Actually, I just restarted my computer and that solved it.  I know that sounds lame and I typically always do that as a last resort but this time I didn't.

Answer (score 0):

By default tika server process keeps running in background and tries to locates **tika-server.jar** in /tmp directory. If that directory gets refreshed and jar is not there you will see  **Tika server returned status:422** error.

You can see the process by running: ps -eaf | grep 'tika'

In our case killing the process worked.